# Scatter matplotlib plot with different x starting points

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to generate a figure like this:

[image: plot]

1) Three different lines
2) Lines don't start at the 'same' x points
3) Later connect those scatter points with lines

```
t = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
a = [2, 3, .............]
b = [ , 1, 2, ..........]
c = [ ,  ,  ,  , 2, ....]
```

Thanks

Comment: That's the default of `plt.plot(x,y, marker="o")`. Have you tried anything?

Comment: The default doesn't work for me using seaborn. Glad you posted this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can use numpy.NaN for y-values without a corresponding t-value. The code would look something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
t = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
a = [2, 3, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN]
b = [np.NaN, 1, 2, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN]
c = [np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, 2, 8]

plt.plot(a,t, marker="o")
plt.plot(b,t, marker="o")
plt.plot(c,t, marker="o")
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was very helpful