# Plotting two graphs with different starting points using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series

What I'm trying to plot is Twitter sentiment and Bitcoin prices.

However, the Twitter data that I have starts from April 17, and the Bitcoin price data starts from May 10th. I want to plot those two on the same graph figure so that sentiment can start plotting from the start but the price data will start plotting later.

When I try to run `matplotlib.pyplot.plot()` I get the error that says they need to be the same dimension. I've also tried to add `0` entries to my price data, but that gives the graph an incorrect representation.

Does anybody know what I might be able to do?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Here's an image I found that's similar to what I'm trying to accomplish, except in my example I want one of my graphs to start later rather than finish earlier. When I try to run something similar in Matplotlib, I get an error message saying that the graphs do not have matching dimensions.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what is unclear about what I'm asking? It would be nice to receive some feedback before voting to close questions, so that people can at least have an idea how they could have made the question better.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54608866/scatter-matplotlib-plot-with-different-x-starting-points) probably solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyZFb.png)You could try removing the first elements of the array containing twitter data. the two arrays must be of same dimension.

Comment: Yes but that would not be what I want to accomplish. I want the graph to plot the Twitter data and then plot the price data later when it starts.

Comment: Oh right, I did not understand your question at first, sorry. the function plot() can receive several arrays, as is said in the documentation of matplotlib. Iḿ going to write here the example of the documentation so you can look at it

Comment: Check the image I added to my answer

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately, it's still not what I'm aiming to accomplish. In your example, let's say I want the red triangles to start at a later point than the other two. Matplotlib gives me an error because the red triangle array does not have the same dimensions as the others.